# How to change the value of type attribute in asp.net?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, button

I have asp.net server side button. I want to change the value of type attribute from submit to button.

Button :

Currently I used the below code to change the value of type attribute

```
 var submitForm = "<%=submitForm.ClientID %>";
 $('#' + submitForm).attr("type", "button");
```

but I found below error :
  **uncaught exception: type property can't be changed**

How can I change the value?

Comment: You are attempting to change the `type` on the `<form>` element, not the submit button itself. If you set the selector to the `id` of the button, your code will work. Why do you need to do this? If you are trying to execute code before the form is submitted, it's simpler to write a submit event handler.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - One assumes the id of the button is `submitForm.ClientId`.

Comment: @Oded If that's true, then `submitForm` is a very poorly named variable.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan - Says what it does...

Comment: @Oded exactly, ids should say what the element *is*, not describe its function.

Comment: Sorry for inconvenience, yes its button ID. I am just trying to give sample code. SO didn't name the button in correct manner.

Comment: I have 5 server side button. When I hit enter, button with ID="btnSendMail" automatically comes to in action.
I want to change its type from submit to button.

Comment: Did not my code help you? It does what you ask.

Comment: I used your code, I am getting this error: $("#" + submitForm).prop is not a function

Answer (score 3, accepted):

please try below code

```
$('#' + submitForm).prop("type", "button");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/qeUxP/

Comment: I am getting this error:  $("#" + submitForm).prop is not a function

Comment: This function was added in JQuery version 1.6. If you click the link it is working. Please update your Jquery. http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Answer (score 1):

The answer works, but seems there is *another (perhaps more fundamental) question* - why even go that route? If you needed a "regular" button, then use a standard html button or a server side HTML button:

If you just want to have a button to script client side:

`<input type="button".... />` instead of `<asp:button....`

If you want the 'best of both worlds' use a "server HTML control":

`<input type="button" runat="server"...../>`

Unsure what you were after, but sometimes it pays to take a step back and take another look....

Comment: Thanks for your valuable comments.